# text underline a different color than the text color in iOS

Tags: ios, uitextview, nsmutableattributedstring

I'm currently using a `UITextView` and setting its `attributedText` property, but I can't see a way to set the underline color different from the text color using my `NSMutableAttributedString`. Am I just missing something? Is this possible?

Do I need to look into `CoreText`? Is it possible there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set two UITextViews with the same text and different colors on top of each other, with the textview underneath underlined.

Comment: oooh. I hadn't thought of this! I'll give it a try!